# Handle(auto dispatch) server errors in React, redux, react-router v4 application with fetch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, fetch

How handle(auto dispatch) server errors when call action creators in one place ?

Fetch data:

```
fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => dispatch({
  type: 'GET_DATA',
  payload: data
}))
```

It can be in component:

```
fetchData() {
  this.props.fetchData().catch(err => {
    // handle this error in root component and delete cookie, logout
    if (err.status === 403) { this.props.setError(err) }

    // handling errors by component
  })
}
```

But by this example it must be duplicate in all methods:

```
catch(err => {
        // handle this error in root component and delete cookie, logout
        if (err.status === 403) { this.props.setError(err) }

        // handling errors by component
      })
```

Or in action creator:

```
fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => dispatch({
  type: 'GET_DATA',
  payload: data
}))
.catch(err => {
    if (err.status === 403) {
      // handle this error in root component and delete cookie, logout
      dispatch({ type: 'SET_ERROR', payload: err })
    }
  })
```

But this check must also be duplicated in every action creators:

```
.catch(err => {
        if (err.status === 403) {
          // handle this error in root component and delete cookie, logout
          dispatch({ type: 'SET_ERROR', payload: err })
        }
      })
```

So, how handle server error and dispatch it in one place without duplicate code  ?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to move all async calls and logic into redux action creators. 

 
Having said that, you can declare a helper function (in `/utils` or `/helpers` folder) which can act like your error handler:

```
function errorHandler(err, dispatch) {
   if (err.status === 403) {
      // handle this error in root component and delete cookie, logout
      dispatch({ type: 'SET_ERROR', payload: err })
    }
}
```

and pass this function's reference to the `.catch` method:

```
.catch(err => errorHandler(err, dispatch))
```